# Message queue for file transfers

Tags: java, activemq-artemis, edi, rocketmq

My question is pretty simple. I'm looking for a MQ solution capable of reliable EDI file transfers along with some metadata attached to it.

I've tried RocketMQ recently and I've come across hardcoded message size limits. I liked RocketMQ because of its simplicity but the lack of documentation and the message size limitation have made me wonder whether there's an alternative.

What would you use for EDI message transfers?

Comment: Check RabbitMQ https://www.rabbitmq.com/

Comment: Kafka is widly used in message transfers, here is a good topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I32hmY4diFY for Kafka as the key component in ETL processes.

Comment: It surely is but the problem with Kafka is that it's really hard to make it work reliably as it puts pretty much all the burden on custom-implemented producers and consumers.Currently, I'm playing with the ActiveMQ Artemis 2.4 which seems to handle the job perfecly, with lots of neat features on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we've been using Apache Artemis for several years now, and I can say that this seems to be the definitive solution. The broker is capable of transferring files up to gigabytes in size, each with their own set of metadata, which is precisely what I was originally after.

https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/